# Examples of calculus on "strange" spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, soft-question, computer-science, recreational-mathematics

I am interested in examples of calculus on "strange" spaces. For example, you can take the derivative of a regular expression[1][2]. Also the concept extends past regular languages, to more general formal languages[3].

You can also do calculus on abstract data types, here is an example in Haskell[4]. Differential equations are type-inference equations. You can also taylor-expand types[5].

I am looking at more examples of this. Note that I am interested where calculus is similar enough to "normal" calculi (e.g. calculus on functions of complex variables, functional calculus, etc). At least operators must be linear, for example the [arithmetic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative) is not interesting to me because the operators are not linear.

The examples I gave are all from computer-science, but I am interested in more general answers.

1. [Brzozowski: Derivatives of Regular Expressions](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321249)
2. [Owens: Regular-expression derivatives reexamined](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~turon/re-deriv.pdf)
3. [Might: Parsing with Derivatives](http://matt.might.net/papers/might2011derivatives.pdf)
4. [The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types, Part 3](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/13/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-part-iii/)
5. [The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types, Part 2](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/11/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-part-ii/)

Comment: Stackoverflow can make questions "community-wiki", looks like I can't make this question community-wiki here?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the term "derivation" in the sense of abstract algebra? Maybe you'd be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative ?

Answer (score 3):

There are some (partial) examples:

**Calculus on normed vector spaces**:

“[Calculus on Normed Vector Spaces](http://www.gbv.de/dms/goettingen/722474865.pdf)” by Rodney Coleman.

"[Calculus on Normed Vector Spaces](http://www.gang.umass.edu/~franz/manifolds.pdf)"

[**Differentiation in Fréchet spaces**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_in_Fr%C3%A9chet_spaces).

**p-adic analysis**:

“[p-Adic Analysis and Lie Groups](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/lectnotes/p-adic-analysis.pdf)” by Peter Schneider.

“[An Introduction to p-adic Numbers and p-adic Analysis](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb/dvi-ps/padicnotes.pdf)” by Andrew Baker.

“[p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/p-adic%20numbers,%20p-adic%20analysis,%20and%20zeta-functions%202nd%20ed.%20-%20N.%20Koblitz.pdf)” by Neal Koblitz.

**Haar integral of a function on a  locally compact topological group**:

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#Haar_integral).

[MSE question about Haar measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494225/what-is-haar-measure).

**[Formal derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative) in ring theory**.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [differential posets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_poset)? (Definitions below from Wikipedia.)

Let $P$ be a locally finite graded poset with unique minimal element. An element $x$ of $P$ is said to *cover* another element $y$ of $P$ if $x>y$ and the rank of $x$ is one more than that of $y$--or equivalently, if $x>y$ but there is no element $z$ of $P$ with $x > z > y$.

Then $P$ is *$r$-differential* if

- For all $x \in P$, exactly $r$ more elements cover $x$ than are covered by $x$.
- For $x, y \in P$ distinct, the number of elements covering both $x$ and $y$ and the number of elements covered by both $x$ and $y$ are the same.

These conditions have an equivalent form as a sort of differential identity involving linear operators on a vector space with basis the elements of $P$. Let $U$ take the basis vector $x \in P$ to the sum of elements covering $x$, and let $D$ take $x$ to the sum of elements covered by $x$. It can be checked that, for basis vectors $x,y$ belonging to the same level of $P$, the scalar $y$-component of $(DU - UD)x$ is the number of elements covering  both $x$ and $y$ minus the number of elements covered by both $x$ and $y$--or, when $x=y$, just the number of elements covering $x$ minus the number covered by $x$.

Thus $P$ is $r$-differential if and only if $$DU-UD = rI.$$

The operator $D$ can be thought of as a differential operator, decreasing the rank of an (non-minimal) element by one just as the derivative decreases the degree of a non-constant polynomial by one. Similarly, $U$ can be thought of as multiplication by a variable. For $1$-differential posets, the above identity is similar to a case of the product rule: $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x f(x) - x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x) = f(x).$$

An interesting $1$-differential poset is [Young's lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_lattice), wherein "differential calculus" on the space of Young diagrams (equivalently, integer partitions) can reveal combinatorial identities about [Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau). Namely, it is an easy consequence of the "product rule" that $D^nU^n(\varnothing)=n!\varnothing$ for $\varnothing$ the minimal element of a $1$-differential poset--just like $\frac{\partial^n }{\partial x^n}x^n=n!$ in calculus. Interpreting standard Young tableaux as covering sequences of Young diagrams, that equation becomes the remarkable *Young-Frobenius identity* as explained on pp. 8-11 by Mitchell Lee [here](http://web.mit.edu/uma/www/mmm/mmm0401.pdf).